# [Stack]: RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds error while testing a function in a NEAR protocol smart contract assemblyscript

Tags: nearprotocol, near, assemblyscript

I get this error on running the test function in my NEAR protocol:

`[Stack]: RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds`

Here is my test function:

```
describe("Main Flow", () => {
it('Tests the flow of the app', () => {
    setContext('hamzatest.testnet', u128.from(0));
    const service1 = contract.addService('gloriajeans.testnet', 'Gloria Jeans', 'Free Coffee', '2023-07-10T15:00:00.000');
}); });
```

Here is the function:

```
  @mutateState()
  addService(provider: string, title: string, description: string, expiryDate: string): Service {

    let expiryDateTimestamp: u64 = Date.fromString(expiryDate).getTime();
    let currentTime: u64 = this._toMillisecond(context.blockTimestamp);
    assert(expiryDateTimestamp > currentTime, Constants.INVALID_EXPIRY_DATE);
    let id = (provider + '/' + currentTime.toString()).toUpperCase();

    let service = new Service(
      id,
      provider,
      title,
      description,
      0,
      currentTime,
      expiryDateTimestamp
    );

    this.services.set(id, service);
    this.services_ids.push(id);

    return service;
  }
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you show how you initialize `services` and `services_ids`?

Comment: `services: PersistentMap<string, Service> = new PersistentMap<string, Service>("services");`
  `services_ids: PersistentVector<string> = new PersistentVector<string>("services_ids");`

Comment: I also want to mention that it is working fine when I call it from the `CLI`